# Deepzoom for WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, deepzoom

Are there any ports to WPF of Silverlight's MultiScaleImage (aka DeepZoom)?  Have Microsoft road-mapped this at all for WPF?

I want to move from WinForms to WPF and require something like DeepZoom, using Silverlight isn't an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment there is no port. However, DeepZoom is based on the technology found in the "World Wide Telescope" and the "Microsoft Photo Synth", so they have desktop versions of the technology running. I guess it would be safe to assume that Microsoft will be releasing a multi scale image control for WPF soon. If you just want the "panning and zooming", and don't care about the efficient breakdown of high resolution images you can certainly achieve the same effects in WPF. This post is [one example on how to do zoom and pan](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/joeyw/archive/2008/08/05/pan-and-zoom-deepzoom-style-in-wpf.aspx).

Comment: You can find a nice implementation of MultiScaleImage for WPF at http://deepzoom.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

Sad bit of news (or 'rumor'?)... in this [List of features to track in WPF4](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2009/05/27/wpf-4-and-net-framework-4-beta-1-list-of-features-totrack.aspx) , Jaime says

"Note: At PDC, we said that DeepZoom would be in WPF4. Unfortunately that feature has been cut. We just could not squeeze it into the schedule.  There are workarounds to it: you can host Silverlight inWPF using web browser control or using the [Silverlight hosting APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296246(VS.95).aspx). "

I guess those [hosting APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296246(VS.95).aspx) might be useful if you're brave - but I'm guessing just putting a Silverlight object inside a WPF WebBrowser control would be simpler...