# Controls for creating a map?

Tags: wpf, dictionary, gis

I need to find a control that can be used to construct a map.

I'm looking for something where a user can specify a location and then drag markers from a toolbar onto the map.  Loading/saving would be a plus

I tried [Telertik Map](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/map.aspx) , [IG](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/data-visualization/xam-map.aspx#Overview) and also [Component One](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/MapsWPF/) but I'm not 100% sure about these products.

Answer (score 1):

You might try hosting [Google Maps in WPF](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/flashmapinwpf.html); it has a fairly complete API.

Any of the components you listed would definitely get the job done (personally, I prefer Infragistics), but they will be expensive.

Finally, you could head a different direction and try to go open-source. [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screenshots&referringTitle=Home) might be worth investigation. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86570/designing-a-wpf-map-control) has more details.

Comment: Thanks Charlie,1000$ is not so much(for IG map) but I want a code that the end user to create a map.

Comment: To be honesty I want to load my custom map to it,(in a building)

Answer (score 0):

There is now a WPF Bing Maps Control
http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2012/01/12/announcing-the-bing-maps-windows-presentation-foundation-control-v1.aspx