# Zooming  an extremely large image

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, zooming

Is there any predefined control in WPF or VS2010 to implement the Image Zooming functionality (like Googlemaps) for a bitmap displayed over a panel using C#? 
My bitmap will be minimum 8GB in Size.

Thanks in advance
Murali

Comment: WPF or Windows Forms or both are ok for you? 8 GB? How are you going to even load such bitmap in the computer's memory?

Comment: for WPF, check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741956/wpf-pan-zoom-image

Comment: See this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552812/image-control-with-pan-and-zoom-ability/2552846#2552846)

Comment: If you don't find one, you need to consider tiling. Loading 8GB into memory is not good (if at all possible!), but you could avoid that by presenting smaller images (tiles) to the user that show him the current view at the current zoom... well, like Googlemaps does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [DeepZoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for Silvelight. There is no such thing in WPF. It was planned for [WPF4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67628/deepzoom-for-wpf/920743#920743), but removed before RTM.

**Update**:
Loading images of this size is pretty uncommon. You should consider tiling as others suggested. Also consider if you really need load all data at once. If the image has size of for example 30000x30000 then the user do not really need/can't to see all this data. Use tiling and appropriate image format (jpg etc) for each zoom level.

Relevant links:

[Single objects still limited to 2 GB in size in CLR 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087982/single-objects-still-limited-to-2-gb-in-size-in-clr-4-0)

[Pushing the Limits of Windows: Physical Memory](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Is there any standard procedure to load the huge bitmaps. I know that there is an Operating System limitation of 2GB even for the 64-bit machines. But I still need to load these images. I dont hink Microsoft hasn't considered this case. Please let me know, if there is any standard procedure to load these huge bitmaps.